# How do I format a two dimensional list to print it a specific way

Tags: python, formatting, format

```
    lst = [[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [3,4,5], [4]]
```

how would I format this so that I could print something that looks like this:

```
    1: [2 3] 
    2: [3 4]
    3: [4 5]
    4: []
```

Any type of advice or hints would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A inline solution because we love them:

```
lst = [[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [3,4,5], [4]]

[print(f"{element[0]}: {element[1:]}") for element in lst]
```

Outputs:

```
1: [2, 3]
2: [3, 4]
3: [4, 5]
4: []
```

Or even **smaller** and **inline**:

```
[print(f"{a}: {b}") for a, *b in lst]
```

Outputs:

```
1: [2, 3]
2: [3, 4]
3: [4, 5]
4: []
```

Note this is equivalent to which doesn't uses print in a list comprehension:

```
for a, *b in lst: print(f"{a}: {b}")
```

Comment: You can do a one-liner print without putting it in a list comprehension by doing arg unpacking: `print(*(f"{element[0]}: {element[1:]}" for element in lst), sep="\n")`

Comment: @Janikas what does 'f' do here?

Comment: The 'f' means you will be formatting the string like:
`name = "Zoxze"`
`print(f"My name is {name}")`
`>>> My name is Zoxze`

Answer (score 3):

Iterate through your list and unpack the elements, printing each one:

```py
for a, *b in mylist:
    print(f"{a}: {b}")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `*` operator:

```
lst = [[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [3,4,5], [4]]

for (head, *tail) in lst:
    print(f"{head}: {tail}")
```

Output:

```
1: [2, 3]
2: [3, 4]
3: [4, 5]
4: []
```

Comment: are head and tail keywords in python? like head knows its the first item and tail knows its all of them besides the first item?

Comment: No - they are variable names. Could have been `foo, *bar` as well. It's the unpacking operator (`*`) that does the magic.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `*` operator to split each list into its first element and the remainder, and `str.join` to format the remainder without the commas.

```
>>> lst = [[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [3,4,5], [4]]
>>> for i, *j in lst:
...     print(f"{i}: [{' '.join(str(n) for n in j)}]")
...
1: [2 3]
2: [3 4]
3: [4 5]
4: []
```